# how to convert epoch time in milliseconds to formatted date using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I do this

```
const d = moment(1623253727754);
console.log(d.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'));
```

and I get this

```
2021-06-09 18:06:75
```

What on Earth is this date? How does it make it 75 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because according to [momentjs docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), 'SS' in CAPITAL S represents fractional seconds, not actual seconds. Try `d.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:ss')`.
Or you could also avoid importing momentjs totally by simply using Javascript's Date method, [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString):

```
const d = new Date(1623253727754);
console.log(d.toISOString());
```